# Polynomial Time Complexity: O(loglog n) = O(n^2)?

Tags: time-complexity

> Is O(loglog n) equal to O(n^2) in polynomial time?

I know O(log n) is eqaul to O(n) in polynomial time because this can change as follows:
log n > 2^(log n) > n^(log 2) > n.

**So, my question is to determine whether O(loglog n) = O(n^2) or not.**

Thank you for your time.

Comment: $O(\log n)$ cannot equal to $O(n)$, because $n$ itself is in $O(n)$, but not in $O(\log n)$.